# Plot String of States on Power BI Maps

Tags: maps, powerbi, sharepoint-online, powerbi-desktop

I want to plot a list of states on Power BI for a given state.

My data has a state, and a list of state names (taken from a multi-choice SharePoint List). It also has a type that can be selected. When a state is selected, it should highlight the list of all related states.

For example, on SharePoint Lists, I have: 
Alabama -> Alabama, Louisiana, North Carolina, West Virginia (of type A) 
Alabama -> Alabama, Alaska, Texas, New York (Type B)

When I select Type A and Alabama, I want the map to highlight Alabama, Louisiana, North Carolina, West Virginia.

Ideas please!

Comment: Can you explain what you have tried? For example have you tried the shape map visual?

Comment: I have tried a bunch of things so far: 
1. Bubble map with a list of states as locations (I don't know how to populate the list of states on this). Same with location map
2. I'm now trying to create a third table with a list of states and lat/longs when selected. 

The problem always boils down to "How do I input a list of states to be highlighted when I select a particular state". 

Can I do something with DAX?